# Errors getting values from 2 MySQL tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am having with my table relationship. I have this table that adds new procurement items, it has 2 columns - `line_manager_remark` and `c_level_remark` that shows the approval status by line manager and a c level executive.

[image]

The values for these columns are gotten from another table

[image]

Now, I am having issues getting the status (definitions) of the items. It does not work.

This is what I have done

```
SELECT
    a.*,
    b.*
FROM
    request_items AS a,
    request_status AS b
WHERE
    a.line_manager_remark = b.id
    AND
    a.c_level_remark = b.id
    AND
    a.request_id = '$id'
    AND
    state = 'active'
```

Comment: *"**Errors getting values** from 2 MySQL tables"* - Being what exactly?

Comment: You should avoid the legacy `FROM a, b WHERE a.id = b.id` syntax for joins and use the explicit `RIGHT/LEFT/OUTER/INNER JOIN` syntax instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
    request_items.*,
    request_status_line_manager.definition AS line_manager_status,
    request_status_c_level.definition AS c_level_status,
FROM
    request_items
    INNER JOIN request_status AS request_status_line_manager
        ON request_items.line_manager_remark = request_status_line_manager.id
    INNER JOIN request_status AS request_status_c_level
        ON request_items.c_level_remark = request_status_c_level.id
WHERE
    request_items.state = 'active'
    AND
    request_items.request_id = '$id'
```

I note - if `'$id'` is evidence of PHP / Perl string interpolation **stop immediately** and use Parameterised Queries, otherwise your query is vulnerable to SQL injection (and I assume `request_items.request_id` is an `int` instead of a text column too...)

Comment: Thanks man. Thats some crazy query